# Apache2 access log 404 480

Tags: php, apache, access-log

when open access.log on the server i see this message

POST "//162.243.67.47:8145/Notification/notifi.php HTTP/1.0" 404 480 "-" "-"

anyone know what is it about and what **404 480 "-" "-"** ????

Answer (score 1):

Here you can read it.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

the `404` is the status code and the `480` are the bytes for the content.

**2326 (%b)**

> The last part indicates the size of the object returned to the client,
>   not including the response headers. If no content was returned to the
>   client, this value will be "-". To log "0" for no content, use %B
>   instead.

If you have a lot of that entries someone try to find some security lags and scan your server. To prevent that you could check `fail2ban`.

http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page